# How to use Game Assets from Behance

Tags: assets

I need to use dinosaur/dragon eggs in my game. I have found out this [resouce](https://www.behance.net/gallery/67841133/Game-Assets-Levelling) from Behance.net. I am not sure how to download these resources. Can anyone help me with it.

Answer (score 1):

This looks to me like an artist's portfolio, a page where they demonstrate their skills to potential employers.

As [Pikalek](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/users/33287/pikalek) points out in the comments, the license specified on these images is [CC BY-NC-ND 4.0](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-nc-nd/4.0/deed.en_US). That means you can download and distribute the images only unmodified, with attribution, and for non-commercial purposes. You can't build upon them/use them in derivative works like your own game without contacting the rights-holder to negotiate a different licence.

Judging by the caption, rights to use these assets in-game are likely exclusively owned by the studio that made Tiny Miners.

So, if you want assets like the ones shown there, hire the artist and pay them to create assets for you.

Comment: There is a [CC BY-NC-ND 4.0 license](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-nc-nd/4.0/deed.en_US) posted at the bottom of the page. That said, I agree that it's a portfolio to showcase work rather than a gallery of assets for download.

Comment: Ah, good catch, I missed the icons and just say the text notice "All member work copyright of respective owner" — I'll update the answer.

Comment: I didn't see it on the first pass & frankly, think they could have presented that info better. Given the affiliation with Adobe, I would have expected better design.